# Buble sort in c using array

Tags: c, arrays

I searched for bubble sort in C using array, stackoverflow provided me tyhe following code, which does not work on descending numbers(1,2,3,4,.....)

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int numArray[5],temp,j;
    printf("Please enter five integers:\n");
    printf("First Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &numArray[0]);
    printf("Second Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &numArray[1]);
    printf("Third Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &numArray[2]);
    printf("Fourth Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &numArray[3]);
    printf("Fifth Number\n");
    scanf("%d", &numArray[4]);

    for (j=0; j<=5; ++j) {
        if (numArray[j] > numArray[j+1]) {
            temp = numArray[j];
            numArray[j] = numArray[j+1];
            numArray[j+1] = temp;
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d ", numArray[j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Update** 
Thank you, using another for loop, I made my ascending numbers bubble sorting code

```
int main()
 { 
       int ara[5]={12,16,14,11,10};
       int i,j,temp; 
       for(i=0;i<5;i++)
       {
         for(j=0;j<=5;j++)
         {
             if(ara[j]>ara[j+1])
             {
                temp=ara[j];
                ara[j]=ara[j+1];
                ara[j+1]=temp;
             }
         }
       }
       for(j=0;j<5;j++)
       printf("%d\n",ara[j]);
  }
```

Comment: Those numbers are ascending

Comment: You're accessing the array out of bounds.

Comment: @RubelAhmed better to update your question with an EDIT section, adding code as a comment is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++) {
        if (numArray[i] > numArray[j]) {
            temp = numArray[j];
            numArray[j] = numArray[i];
            numArray[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @RubelAhmed in case you didn't know, this isn't bubble sort. [Bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) has complexity `O(n)` in best-case if the list is already sorted, `O(n^2)` worst-case. This is purely `O(n^2)` no matter what, and doesn't ripple up pairs as bubble-sort should.

Comment: @WhozCraig..may u provide the best answer, so we also learn how to do in correct way. thank you.

Comment: @wqrahd certainly, i'll throw a simple bubblesort sample together. give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your array to have length 5 `int numArray[5]`
Hence, you only have indices `0,1,2,3,4` available.
Thus your loop `for (j=0; j<=5; ++j)` will yield an index `5` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Adding to the brimstone, it will actually dereference `numArray[j+1]` or in this case `numArray[6]`; two slots beyond redemption.

Comment: Good call, overlooked that one

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below given code , i have added logic to your code and its working fine now

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

int numArray[5],temp,j;

printf("Please enter five integers:\n");
printf("First Number\n");
scanf("%d", &numArray[0]);
printf("Second Number\n");
scanf("%d", &numArray[1]);
printf("Third Number\n");
scanf("%d", &numArray[2]);
printf("Fourth Number\n");
scanf("%d", &numArray[3]);
printf("Fifth Number\n");
scanf("%d", &numArray[4]);


int len = sizeof(numArray)/sizeof(numArray[0]);
printf("len of array %d \n", len);
int i=0;
for(i = 0;i<len;i++)
{
        for (j=0; j<len-i-1; j++) {

                if (numArray[j] > numArray[j+1]) {
                        temp = numArray[j];
                        numArray[j] = numArray[j+1];
                        numArray[j+1] = temp;
                }
        }
}
for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        printf("%d ", numArray[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int swaped = 1;
while(swaped){
    swaped =0;
    for (j=0; j<5-1,; ++j) {//-1 for (j+1) upper bound is 4
        //descending order : When the order of reverse exchange
        if (numArray[j] < numArray[j+1]) {
            temp = numArray[j];
            numArray[j] = numArray[j+1];
            numArray[j+1] = temp;
            swaped = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the more efficient way to do this is,

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<5; j++) {
        if (numArray[i] > numArray[j]) {
           temp = numArray[j];
           numArray[j] = numArray[i];
           numArray[i] = temp;
       }
    }
}
```